# How to remove required attribute in MVC4, although that has been made required in model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-validation

I am not able to do the same thing with string properties. In the below code, I want to remove the validation of the 'Last Name' and make it optional.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]    
[Display(Name="Last Name")]
public string LastName { get; set; }
```

Comment: Delete this line from your model - `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]`.  Recompile and that property will no longer be required.

Comment: I want to remove the validation from my View. Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add following java-script to your view and it will to remove the `required` rule for `LastName` although it has been made required in model.

```
$("#LastName").rules("remove", "required");
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have applied the logic, but I got another problem. ModelState is not getting Valid. ModelState.IsValid returning false.

Comment: That's because you have defined the `LastName` as `Required` in model. Either you have to remove the `ModelState.IsValid` check and do the validation separately for fields or you can add `ModelState["LastName"].Errors.Clear();` before you check the status. Then it will clear the model errors for `LastName` field all the time.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't want the validation why are you setting it in the model ?

Comment: The model is created for general purpose. I am using this model to create dynamic form as per different requirement. I want to use the same model and generate the forms. If I want to disable validation of a field then that is going to be difficult one.

Comment: How can I make Validation Enable again?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ModelState to be valid then try this:

```
   ModelState["LastName"].Errors.Clear();
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   // your logic
}
```

if you want to disable clientside validations then :

```
  @Html.EnableClientValidation(false);
```

**Note:** this will disable all the client side validations.

Comment: Thank you. That is understood. My question: I have given required attribute for the field Last Name. Now I want to remove from Client side. Is this possible for that field only? Please help.

Comment: @SubrataChakraborty you can disable client side validation for specific field with this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44473250/3089009

Answer (score 0):

You can disable client side validation for specific field with this

```
<form method="post">
   // to disable client-side validaiton for model.SomeValue
   @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(false); } 
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeValue)<br />
   @{ Html.EnableClientValidation(true); }
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

or you can omit ModelState Error for specific field in controller side with this

```
ModelState.Remove("SomeValue"); // to omit SomeValue Validation Error

if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
   //Do some stuff, eventually redirect elsewhere
}
```